# Can't Show Google Map in Android WebView

Tags: android, google-maps, webview

I have an aspx page which had already integrated google map api and can displayed the google map , then I want to show it in the android webview, but the webview can not be displayed the google map .
this aspx page can run perfectly in android browser.

Here is Logcat print:

I / chromium: [INFO: CONSOLE (210)] "Google Maps API warning: NoApiKeys https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#no-api-keys", source: http: //maps.google.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/25/11/util.js (210)

I / chromium: [INFO: CONSOLE (210)] "Google Maps API warning: SensorNotRequired https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#sensor-not-required", source: http: //maps.google.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/25/11/util.js (210)

Here is the code about setting webview:

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);//
        webView.getSettings().setGeolocationEnabled(true);//
        webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);//
        webView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);//
        webView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDefaultZoom(WebSettings.ZoomDensity.FAR);
        webView.getSettings().setBlockNetworkImage(false);
        webView.getSettings().setBlockNetworkLoads(false);
        String dir = this.getApplicationContext().getDir("database", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getPath();
        webView.getSettings().setGeolocationDatabasePath(dir);
```

Comment: I am also facing the same issue please let me know if u get any solution.

Comment: anyone have the solutions right now?

Answer (score 2):

just add this line after

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);//

webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

Answer (score 0):

Based from your code, I can't find the `loadUrl` which loads the given `URL`.

Compatibility note. Applications targeting `N` or later, JavaScript state from an empty WebView is no longer persisted across navigations like [`loadUrl`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadUrl(java.lang.String)). For example, global variables and functions defined before calling loadUrl(String) will not exist in the loaded page. Applications should use [`addJavascriptInterface(Object, String)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface(java.lang.Object, java.lang.String)) instead to persist JavaScript objects across navigations.

To provide a WebView in your own Activity, include a  in your layout, or set the entire Activity window as a WebView during onCreate():

```
WebView webview = new WebView(this);
setContentView(webview);
```

Then load the desired web page:

```
webview.loadUrl("http://slashdot.org/");
```